# ASP.Net Core MVC save to database method is not fired for the first time.After I go back and fire it again it works perfectly

Tags: asp.net, routes, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an app in which I post some JSON data to my server and then create an object that will later be added to a database.This is done by the "Save" method in my "SendItemsController":

```
 [Route("SendItems/Save")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SendItemsController : Controller
    {
        private AppDbContext _db;

      
        public SendItemsController(AppDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [Consumes("application/json")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Save([FromBody] ShoppingCart s)
        {
           await _db.ShoppingCarts.AddAsync(s);
           await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        [HttpGet("~/ThankYou/Index")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        
    }
```

After the object is added to the database I try to redirect the client to a "ThankYou" page.
When first launched when I press my order button on the "Cart" page it redirects the client to the "ThankYou" page without firing the "Save" method, but if I go back from the "ThankYou" page to the "Cart" page and hit the button again, the method is fired, the object is added to the database and the client is redirected to the "ThankYou" page, just as it should.My question is what should I change to my code in order to make it fire from the first time, not after going back and hitting the order button again.
I will provide the code that I have written.

Here is the javascript that I use in order to form my JSON object and then POST it to my server:

```
 var orderB = document.getElementById("orderB");
        orderB.addEventListener("click", function () {
          
            var inputName = document.getElementById("inputName").value;
            var inputAddress = document.getElementById("inputAddress").value;
            var inputMail = document.getElementById("inputMail").value;
            var auxArray = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < productsAux.length; i++) {
                if (productsAux[i]!="") {
                auxArray[i-1] = { "productName": productsAux[i].titlu, "productPrice": productsAux[i].pret, "quantity": localStorage.getItem(productsAux[i].titlu) };
                }
            }
            var shoppingCart = {
                productList: auxArray,
                clientName: inputName,
                clientAddress: inputAddress,
                clientMail: inputMail
            };
            
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(shoppingCart),
                url: "senditems/save",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                
            })
            
        })
```

And here is the html for my form that I use to gather the name,address and email from the client :

```
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <label id="clientName"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <input  id="inputName" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <label id="clientAddress"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <input  id="inputAddress" type="text" />
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <label id="clientMail"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <input  id="inputMail" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>

   

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-3 offset-4">
            <button  class="btn btn-primary " id="orderB" asp-controller="SendItems" action="Save">ORDER</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Looks like the ORDER button will submit as well as the JavaScript. Bit of a guess which one is first. Or which one succeeds.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: Try one or the other. Not sure why you would need JavaScript here.

Comment: If you do want to use JS, then dumb down the button:  add `"type="button"` and remove the Action and Controller attributes.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I use it in order to build my JSON object.In my cart page I dont have an input for my JSON data.The project is a clothing site and I pass the data around the pages with local storage.When the client decides to purchase something they go to the cart page and there they fill the form.In my javascript I build that JSON and when the client hits "ORDER" the name,address,email and products form a C# object that is then added to the database.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I dumbed down the button and set it's type to "button" but now it does not redirect the client to anything it just refreshes the cart page.Though the object is formed and is added to the database.

Comment: No, I don't think JavaScript will/can  redirect.

Comment: I forgot how MVC binding works but when you link the inputs `name="ClientName"` I think the default binding will work. Otherwise, find a tutorrial for MVC forms. That array might be a bit of a puzzle.

Comment: @HenkHolterman How is what I want to do supposed to be done?

Comment: I tried sending the data [FromForm] but the values are null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,I am not sure if you have provided the whole ajax,because an ajax requested action will not let you redirect in the backend.You could only redirect it in your ajax function.

Secondly,you have added the onclick event,no need to add asp-controller tag helper it would render wrong formaction.

Thirdly,the item `i` starts with 0 but the index of `auxArray` starts with -1,the product array may not pass to the backend successfully.

At last,the ajax url should be:`/senditems/save`.

Here is a working demo like below:

Model:

```
public class ShoppingCart
{
    public string clientName { get; set; }
    public string clientAddress { get; set; }
    public string clientMail { get; set; }
    public List<Product> productList { get; set; }
}
public class Product
{
    public string productName { get; set; }
    public int productPrice { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<form>
    //....  
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-3 offset-4">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="orderB" type="button">ORDER</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        var orderB = document.getElementById("orderB");
        orderB.addEventListener("click", function () {    
            var inputName = document.getElementById("inputName").value;
            var inputAddress = document.getElementById("inputAddress").value;
            var inputMail = document.getElementById("inputMail").value;
            var auxArray = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                auxArray[i] = { "productName": "aaaa", "productPrice": 34, "quantity": 3 };
            }
            var shoppingCart = {
                productList: auxArray,
                clientName: inputName,
                clientAddress: inputAddress,
                clientMail: inputMail
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(shoppingCart),
                url: "/senditems/save",  //add `/`
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                success: function (res) {
                    window.location.href = res; //redirect like this
                }
            })

        })
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
[Route("SendItems/Save")]
[ApiController]
public class SendItemsController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Consumes("application/json")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Save([FromBody] ShoppingCart s)
    {
        return Json("YourRedirectUrl");
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]